# How do I block switch to tab on firefox?

Tags: firefox

[image]

From the looks of it, I can't block it : (

What's wrong?

Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to block that action. Iirc you can't change that. You can allow it by unchecking allow default though, but that's obvious.